# Console in the x86 program

Tags: windows, assembly, console, x86

```
.386
.model  flat, stdcall
option  casemap:none

include windows.inc
include kernel32.inc
include user32.inc

includelib user32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib

Main        proto

.data

hOutput dd 0
bReadWritten dd 0
szText1 db "What's your name?",0

hInput dd 0

szInput db 128 dup(0)



.data?

.code
start:

Invoke Main
Invoke ExitProcess,0

Main proc
    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov hOutput, eax

    invoke GetStdHandle,STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    mov hInput, eax

    invoke lstrlen, addr szText1
    invoke WriteFile, hOutput, addr szText1, eax, ADDR bReadWritten, NULL

    invoke ReadFile, hInput, addr szInput, 128, ADDR bReadWritten,0



    ret
Main endp   


end start
```

Nothing happened after executing this program. Why the console window didn't appear?

**Postscriptum**

Assemble options(winAsm):

> /Zi /Zd /c /coff /Cp /nologo

Linker options

> /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /DEBUG /DEBUGTYPE:CV /VERSION:4.0 /INCREMENTAL:NO

Comment: What assembler? Did you link this?

Comment: winAsm , I pressed the "Go All" button

Comment: It is a linker problem, you didn't specify the /SUBSYSTEM correctly.

Comment: The values in options that I've listed in the postscriptum are default. @Hans Passant are you sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
```

Now it is answerable.  That's the wrong option, that declares that the program is a native Windows program.  Which takes care of creating its own windows, using the CreateWindow() api function.  Which you can certainly call from an assembly program as well, just not commonly done.  You'd at least use a C compiler to go through the rigamarole of creating a window class and properly writing the window procedure.  Like Petzold showed us in his seminal "Programming Windows" book.

If you want Windows to create a console window for you then you have to ask for it:

```
/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

Comment: added code blocks. Two comments, though: Iczelion has fairly nice examples of assembly programs using windows and your use of "native" in the answer is actually rather confusing in reference to `/subsystem:windows`, because that'd be the Win32 subsystem, whereas `/subsystem:native` (which exists) calls for no subsystem whatsoever (sometimes referred to as "native subsystem", though - even by MS) used for drivers, KM DLLs or even native UM applications such as `autochk.exe`.